# CD/DVD not working after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

After Windows 10 was upgraded, CD/DVD (TSSTcorp CDDVDW SU-208DB) stopped working.

> Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)

I was trying to uninstall and reinstall, but no success. Any hints?

**EDIT:**

Registry looks like this:

[image: Registry]

**EDIT2:**

Connection:

[image: Connection]

Comment: @Psycogeek I do not see any upper or lower filter in my registry.

Comment: That is it, all ok. (removing comment)  As a side , one thing that shows different here (win7)  is (default) has a name "DVD/CD-ROM drives" I could not believe that changes anything at all.  What port on the motherboard is it connected to?  whos controller?

Comment: @Psycogeek I do not know the physical connection, it's a Toshiba laptop with warranty. Maybe the Device Manager connection will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed that by uninstalling the Toshiba Recovery Media Creator. (But I do not know why...)

Comment: Thank you! This worked after everything Microsoft suggests did not (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314060).

Answer (score 4):

OK did a Windows logo key -R. entered regedit.

Went to HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\atapi

Under it I created a folder called 'Controller0'

In Controller0 I did a 'New' (left click) and typed in 'EnumDevice1'  as 'RegDWORD' and modified it to binary '1' in hex.

Exit regedit and restart computer

After the restart, I can now see the CD/DVD in device manager.

Now I can try to reload the device drivers.

This did work for me. The '?' has left my USB devices, thumbnail, nook, ipod, etc. The device manager now confirms I have a working CD/DVD but I stuck in a game and was able to start it, :) My Pc now shows the device as well, it didn't before. Hope it works for you because I have spent days trying to get this thing back again.

Comment: The '?' on other USB thumb drives, Nook and Ipod devices is gone. I can reach them now. I put a game in the CD, it loaded.

Comment: What this `In Controller0 I did a 'New' (left click) and typed in 'EnumDevice1' as 'RegDWORD' and modified it to binary '1' in hex.` actually do?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my Samsung (TSSTcorp CDDVDW) on Windows 10. So I went out and purchased a new CDDVDW by ASSUS. Windows 10 could not find it either. Went back to Windows 7 and now I have 2 CDDVDW working just as good as before. It appears to me that in order to go with windows 10 I will have to replace my motherboard with a windows 10 compatible. Hopefully, my I7 quad core will work on a new motherboard if in fact an 1155 socket is acceptable to windows 10.