# Audio files not read on CD audio and video DVD on Windows 10

Tags: audio, windows-10, dvd

I have some problems with DVDs and CDs since I upgraded from Windows 7 (64bit) to Windows 10:

- first, my computer didn't recognize at all my DVD reader: no icon, no error message, no conflict related in peripheric installation. When I tried to "search" a new peripheric, it simply did not find it. On BIOS, it was indeed present, idem when I booted on DVD with a bootable disk.
- I could finally install the reader putting directly on the registry the solution proposed here : [CD/DVD not working after upgrade to Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/952156/cd-dvd-not-working-after-upgrade-to-windows-10), and I thank very much for the solution. drivers files are verified -> no need to update.
- Now, I can read the content of a data's DVD or CD, but sound is mute on all audio CD's ( on Windows player: the files are recognized, the cd is recognized, working simply as if the audio was put on "mute") , and if I can read videos with VCL, music of film is sometimes OK, but on most (commercial original) DVDs, speaking is totally mute either switched in french (my country) or in English (I verified that the geographic zone is 2 and didn't change it) .I precise that music sound is otherwise OK on my computer (realplayer) it only occurs with CD and DVD

Could someone explain to me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found myself the solution : I uninstalled the pilots of Realtek... and reinstalled it. Everything works fine now. I just don't know why no conflict clearly appeared before.